# How to structure elements with multiple characteristics in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have a set of elements (A, B, C, D...) that all have two or more characteristics (each one has a color, a shape, etc...), how can I make a structure so that I can easily ask for a list of all green elements, or of all round elements?
I thought of using a dictionary but I don't know if this will be the most efficient way to achieve that. I know that the value of each characteristic for each object will never change. There aren't a lot of characteristics, but there is a lot of objects.

Here is what a set would look like:

```
test = {'ob1': {'color': ['green'], 
                'shape': 'round'},
        'ob2': {'color': ['red'], 
                'shape': 'round'},
        'ob3': {'color': ['green', 'yellow'], 
                'shape': 'cubic'}
        }
```

I would like an easy way to obtain the list containing [ob1, ob2], if I want to obtain all the green objects. But at the same time, I would want to still be able to easily find the properties of a given object (I would like to know what color and shape is obj1 for example).

Comment: As you have not provided any input and output. I would assume just by the statement of yours the preferable structure could be `class` and `dict`. It would be useful if you could provide the input, what have you tried and expected output.

Comment: if we can see your code we will say if using dict or class better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use namedtuple which is an efficient data format.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Element = namedtuple('Element', 'color size id name')

ELEMENTS_DB = {'e1':Element('green', 12, 34, 'jack'),
               'e2':Element('blue', 132, 334, 'dan'),
               'e3':Element('green', 142, 434, 'ben')}

# get green elements
green_elements = [e for e in ELEMENTS_DB.values() if e.color == 'green']
print(green_elements)
# get 'e3' 
print(ELEMENTS_DB['e3'])
```

Output:

```
[Element(color='green', size=12, id=34, name='jack'), Element(color='green', 
  size=142, id=434, name='ben')]
Element(color='green', size=142, id=434, name='ben')
```

Comment: This method seems great, but is there a way to know the other characteristics of a given element (for example, if we have the str 'jack', how can we know that 'jack' is color:green, size:12 and id:34?)

Comment: I am not sure I get your question. Can you please try to explain again? If the Element has an identifier like 'id' or 'name' and you want to be able to fetch a single Element from  ELEMENTS_DB, you will have to use a dict and use the identifier as a key.

Comment: In my example dictionary, if I write ```test['ob1']```, I will get all of the properties of ob1. If I write ```test['ob1']['color']```, I will get more precisely its color. Can I do something like that with the ELEMENT_DB you made for example?
Edit: Okay, thanks. So I would have to use both a dictionary and a namedtuple structure to do what I want?

Comment: No, You can not because ELEMENTS_DB has no key. When you do call 'test['ob1']' you point to a single object. You can not find all 'green' elements this way. So you need to explain what kind of queries you want to call.

Comment: Code was modified in order to support your needs, ELEMENTS_DB is a dict where the key is a string and the value us a namedtuple

Comment: I'm going to be stupid, but what is the difference here with something like ```green_elements = [e for e in test if test[e]['color'] is 'green']``` used with a normal dictionary, without namedtuple? Or is namedtuple more efficient than a dictionary?

Comment: namedtuple is much more efficient and gives the developer 'strong typing' (e['color'] vs e.color])

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your data look like, so it's hard to make a recommendation, but this looks like a job for `pandas`. Pandas can create a dataframe which basically acts like a spreadsheet. Once the data are imported, you can filter and sort based on characteristics. Dictionaries will be fine in most cases though. See [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is a good way to do it in my opinion. But you can certainly use dictionaries:

```
elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
colors = ['red','red', 'blue', 'red']
shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'circle', 'triangle']


dict1 = { element: {'color':colors[index], 'shape':shapes[index]} for index,element in enumerate(elements)}


def find_keys(keyword):
    result = []
    for key, val in dict1.items():
        for k, v in val.items():
            if v == keyword:
                result.append(key)
    return result

print (find_keys('red'))
```

**Output:**

```
 print (find_keys('red'))
['A', 'B', 'D']

print (find_keys('circle')) 
['B', 'C']
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but wouldn't it take a long time if there were a lot of elements in dict1? So is panda a more efficient solution in this case?

Comment: Most likely since it has to iterate over each key. Like I said in the solution I’d probably just use pandas and filter on the columns. was just offering a solution with dictionaries to give options.

Answer (score 0):

Normally questions demonstrate non-working code for answers to help get working.

One way to do this would be to have a dictionary whose keys are the characteristics, with each value being another dictionary whose keys are the possible values of each attribute. Its values would be a set of the elements having the given value for the property.

All green elements would then be

```
elements['colour']['green']
```

All round elements would be

```
elements['shape']['circle']
```

By using set operations it will then be easy to find the round green objects, for example, with

```
elements['colour']['green'].intersection(elements['shape']['circle'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use classes:

```
class element:
    def __init__(self,shape,color):
        self.shape=shape
        self.color=color
```

query function:

```
def query(data,shape=None,color=None):
     if shape:
         data=[x for x in data if x.shape==shape]
     if color:
         data=[x for x in data if x.color==color]
     return data
```

using:

```
red_circle=element("circle","red")
red_square=element("square","red")
blue_circle=element("circle","blue")
blue_square=element("square","blue")

data=[red_circle,red_square,blue_circle,blue_square]
qdata=query(data,color="blue")

for x in qdata:
    print("shape: {} - color: {}".format(x.shape,x.color))
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I've been taught that classes are more efficient for object with changing characteristics. As my set will remain non changed, I thought it would be more convenient to create a dictionary?

Comment: problems can have multiple solutions ofcourse you can solve this problem with dictionaries